# Redux not passing state to props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I connected a component to the store in a way that it's able to dispatch actions and receive state. The dispatch works and I can see the state change in the Redux dev tool. However, I'm unable to pass the state back to the component. What am I missing here?

**Component**

The toggle() and addTask() are successfully dispatched. However, the newTask doesn't receive the state.

```
class AddTask extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  };

  setValue = value => this.setState({ value });

  handleInput = () => !this.props.newTask ? 'hidden' : '';
  handleToggle = () => this.props.toggle();

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const title = this.state.value;
    this.props.addTask(title);
    this.props.toggle();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="add-task">
        <div className="btn-add-task">
          <Button 
            type="LINK" 
            label="Add a Task" 
            onClick={this.handleToggle}
          />
        </div>
        <form 
          className={`task-input ${this.handleInput()}`} 
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        >
          <InputField
            placeholder="Task title"
            value={value => this.setValue(value)}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default AddTask;
```

**Container**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import AddTask from './TaskList/AddTask/AddTask';

import * as actionCreators from '../actions/taskActions';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  newTask: state.newTask,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(AddTask);
```

**Reducer**

```
import {
  TOGGLE_TASK,
} from '../constants/actions';

const uiReducer = (state = {
  newTask: false,
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_TASK:
      return {
        ...state,
        newTask: !state.newTask,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default uiReducer;
```

**Store**

```
const initialState = {
  tasks: [
    {
      title: 'Title A', description: 'Description A', effort: '12 hrs', editing: 'false',
    },
    {
      title: 'Title B', description: 'Description B', effort: '24 hrs', editing: 'false',
    },
    {
      title: 'Title C', description: 'Description C', effort: '', editing: 'false',
    },
  ],
  ui: {
    newTask: false,
  },
};
```

**Print**

```
tasks: Array(4)
0: {title: "Title A", description: "Description A", effort: "12 hrs", editing: "false"}
1: {title: "Title B", description: "Description B", effort: "24 hrs", editing: "false"}
2: {title: "Title C", description: "Description C", effort: "", editing: "false"}
3: {id: "", title: "asdfasd", description: undefined}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
ui:
newTask: false
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post how your reducer looks like? There might be something wrong with it. Thanks :)

Comment: First thing, are you using the container and not the component in your app. Second thing if you use combineReducers in your app, state.newTask might not be the correct value you are trying to access. It would instead be nested inside another object which is the name of your reducer

Comment: @devDesigner you should use newTask like `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  newTask: state.ui.newTask,
});`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I added the reducer and the initial state, which matches the actual state as shown in the dev tools.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I already tried, but it didn't work

Comment: @devDesigner, What does state in mapStateToProps print. also make sure you are using the connected container and not the component directly

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It's a boolean. So if false, then if false then 'hidden' should be added to the className. What do you mean with using the connected container? The way it's set up now is that the container dispatches actions and receives state for the AddTask component.

Comment: What I mean is, are you using the container and not importing AddTask whereever you render it from `import AddTask from './TaskList/AddTask/AddTask';`. Also what I wanted to know was whether you get the correct store state in mapStateToProps and hence I asked what does `console.log(state)` print in mapStateToProps

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri So are you saying that I should render AddTask inside the container component?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that, Also given that mapStateToProps is being called, you would have used it correctly and state.ui.newTask should would correctly in mapStateToProps

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I added the print to the description. Surprisingly, I was unable to console log from the AddTaskContainer, so I had a look at the parent that contains AddTask and TaskList and found out that I was rendering AddTask instead of AddTaskContainer inside the parent. I updated the component and also changed state.newTask to state.ui.newTask and now it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @devDesigner that is exactly what I was trying to communicate to you which Unfortunately I couldn't